# Velocity in AWS Api Gateway: how to access array of objects

Tags: aws-api-gateway, velocity, vtl

So in AWS Api Gateway, I'm querying my DynamoDB and gets this JSON as reply:

https://pastebin.com/GpQady4Z

So, Items is an array of 3 objects. I need to extract the properties of those objects: TS, Key and CamID.

I'm using Velocity in the Integration Response. Here is my Mapping Template:

```
#set($count = $input.json('$.Count'))
#set($items = $input.json('$.Items'))
{
"count" : $count,
"items" : $items,
"first_item": $items[0]
},
```

The result from API Gateway:

```
{
"count" : 3,
"items" : [{"TS":{"N":"1599050893346"},"Key":{"S":"000000/000000_2020-08-02-12.48.13.775-CEST.mp4"},"CamID":{"S":"000000"}},{"TS":{"N":"1599051001832"},"Key":{"S":"000000/000000_2020-08-02-12.50.01.220-CEST.mp4"},"CamID":{"S":"000000"}},{"TS":{"N":"1599051082769"},"Key":{"S":"000000/000000_2020-08-02-12.51.22.208-CEST.mp4"},"CamID":{"S":"000000"}}],
"first_item": 
}
```

first_item always returns empty value

While in a pure array like this:

```
#set($foo = [ 42, "a string", 21, $myVar ])
"test" : $foo[0]
```

"test" returns 42

Why is my code not working on array of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$items` is a JSON string (not JSON object), so `$items[0]` doesn't make sense.

If you want to access the first item, use `$input.json('$.Items[0]')`.

If you want to iterate over them, you can convert the JSON string to object first using [`$util.parseJson()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference)

Comment: Yes I tried this before. The problem with this method is I can't iterate like this:
$input.json('$.Items[$i]')
Because it doesn't evaluate $i
It's also not working with foreach